# Blazor chart vertical line

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

I'm trying hard to make dashboard with Blazor. But I'm new to js and css so feel some hard.

Currently I'm implementing chart components and I'd like to add vertical line which is moved automatically like below image.

I searched a lot of pages, however I didn't even know what to do.

I'm not asking you to write code, but it would be nice to tell me about sites, methods or libraries that I can refer to.

[image]

### Situation

I'm using [Blazorise Chart](https://blazorise.com/docs/extensions/chart/) .net core 5.0

### My tries

- Create a data set to be expressed like a vertical line, set a timer, and move the vertical line data once per second.(The StateHasChange() function should be continues to be called.
- Draw vertical line using css(But I couldn't know how to move it)

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Since Blazorise uses ChartJs internally to draw the charts, you might be able to use the [ChartJs annotation plugin](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation). You might need to leverage a JavaScript Interop method to inject the plugin options.

Alternatively you can simply draw the line yourself, as the Chart renders in a `<canvas />` element:

Heres a piece of code i use (Personally I use [ChartJs.Blazor](https://github.com/mariusmuntean/ChartJs.Blazor), and my chart is a Bar chart, so you will need to adapt the code to fit your own needs and library)

```
annotationConfig: function (canvasID, indexToDrawAt) {
            var originalLineDraw = Chart.controllers.bar.prototype.draw;
            Chart.helpers.extend(Chart.controllers.bar.prototype, {
                draw: function () {
                    originalLineDraw.apply(this, arguments);

                    var chart = this.chart;
                    var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;

                    var index = chart.config.options.lineAtIndex;
                    if (index) {

                        var xaxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
                        var yaxis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'];

                        var x1 = xaxis.left;
                        var y1 = yaxis.getPixelForValue(index);

                        var x2 = xaxis.right;
                        var y2 = yaxis.getPixelForValue(index);

                        ctx.save();
                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
                        ctx.strokeStyle = '#3C3E4F';
                        ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
                        ctx.stroke();
                        ctx.restore();
                    }
                }
            });
        
        let chart = window.ChartJsInterop.BlazorCharts.get(canvasID);
        chart.options.lineAtIndex = indexToDrawAt;
        chart.update();
    }
```

This code adds a option to the chart called lineAtIndex, which when set, draws a line across the canvas at the provided index.

I use the method as such:

```
if (ShowAvgLine)
    {
        if (currentAverage != 0.0)
            {
                jSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("generalInterop.annotationConfig", _config.CanvasId, currentAverage);
            }
    }
```

If you get the above to work with your library, you might try your previous solution of making timed calls to the interop method to move it.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know Blazorise Chart, maybe there is also a built in solution.

If you want to solve it in a pretty hacky way, you could just create a `<div>` which has the same height as your chart. Then you can use the `top` and `left` [CSS properties](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/top-right-bottom-left/) to set the `div` at the leftmost position over the chart (you may have to give the `div` a [z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) and a `position: absolute` so that it appears over the chart). The positions should be saved in a C# variable. Now you can implement a [function which gets called every second](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=net-5.0) which increments the `left` value and calls the `StateHasChanged()` method.

This is a really hacky solution but it should work as expected. But you have to beware, that on different devices the chart can be displayed in a other way, so maybe the `div` won´t align anymore.